# Can't scroll within mobile drop down nav

Tags: html, css

I am having some troubles with the mobile menu landscape, - I am unable to scroll. To clearify I ment by scrolling so I see the whole menu. When scrolling now, it stopps after a certain amount of px (the height of the header). Please minimize the window so it looks like mobile landscape if you want to take a look by yourself.

[image]
As the image shows, you are not able to see the the whole menu.

The problem is the following:

```
header {
        position: fixed;
}
```

It needs to be fixed, but I must be able to scroll. Any suggestions?

I have tried to remove some part of the code to make it easier to understand.

**HTML**

```
<header class="nav-down">
    <nav class="navbar navbar navbar-fixed-top site-navigation" role="navigation">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Aarseth-Navbar">
                <section class="si-icons si-icons-default">
                    <span class="si-icon si-icon-hamburger-cross" data-icon-name="hamburgerCross"></span>
                </section>
            </button>
            <div id="navbar-brand-cont">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
                    <img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/img/logo.jpg">
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="Aarseth-Navbar">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'menu' => 'Hovedmeny', 'menu_class' => 'nav-menu' )); ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>
```

**CSS**

```
header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}

.nav-up {
    top: -120px;
}

.navbar-fixed-top { 
    position: absolute;
}

.nav-menu { 
    margin-top: 90px;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
}


@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    header {
        height: 100px;  
    }

    .site-navigation ul {
        display: block; 
    }
    #Aarseth-Navbar ul li {
        clear: both;
        margin-left: 0;
        float: none;
        display:block;
        margin-top: 15px;
        padding-bottom: 15px;
    }

    .navbar-collapse {
        height: auto;
        max-height:none;
        margin-top: 20px;
        padding-left: 0;
        padding-right: 0;
    }

    #Aarseth-Navbar {
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .navbar-nav {
        width: 100%;    
    }

    .menu-hovedmeny-container {
        padding-top: 0px;   
    }

    .nav-menu {
        padding-left: 0px;  
        padding-bottom: 0px;
    }

    .site-navigation ul {
        width: 100%;    
    }

    .menu-hovedmeny-container {
        padding-right: 0px; 
    }

    .navbar-brand {
        padding-bottom: 0px;    
    }
    .sub-menu {
        display: block; 
        width: 100%;
        position: relative;
    }

    .navbar-collapse {
        max-height: none!important;
    }
}
```

If you want to take a look:
http://goo.gl/GZaM5K

Note: I am working on fixing the menu icon right now, so if you don't see it, press at the right corner where it's naturally that the hamburger/menu icon is. The href works, its just the svg that I am having some troubles with.

Please ask if something is unclear.

Comment: What do you mean you can't scroll? I just took a look and resized the browser and was able to scroll

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. To clearify I ment by scrolling so I see the whole menu. When scrolling now, it stopps after a certain amount of px (the height of the header). Please minimize the window so it looks like mobile landscape.

Comment: Please try explain your situation further - can't scroll the nav on mobile? Also, here is a fiddle I made creating a cool hamburger *menu https://github.com/camdevcam/responsive_fiddle if helps

Comment: OK I see, let me relook

Comment: Thank you. I will upload a image now.

Comment: its your icon? too big...Also use media @media screen for all sizes

Comment: Let me know if you still can't get it.. but this should work, had a similar problem a few months ago. Make sure it's in your mobile css and it's the correct selector for the nav that appears on click in mobile.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

If you want your mobile, drop-down nav to be scrollable you have to define a `height` with the wrapper `div` that you coded to encase the mobile nav. You should define a height, and you should set `overflow-y` to `scroll` and might as well add `touch` scroll.

```
#MobileMenuDivWrapper { 
  height: 200px;
  max-height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch; // mobile safari
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes, that works. But not quite what I was looking for, but I will try to include some additional CSS to make it look better. Will comment in a second after I have testet it.

Comment: I believe it works. I also removed the scroll-bar at the right in the window, so it looked better. However, I am wondering if there is a trick to get the right amount of height? I believe it should change acordring to the screen height. I was trying to make it 100vh, but it didn't work. Any ideas? JS or something?

Comment: Open a separate question!

Answer (score 8):

The issue for me was the `height` units (from [this forum](https://forum.webflow.com/t/scroll-problems-with-a-fixed-sidebar-on-mobile-devices/26050/5)).

I had to change the `height` in the menu `div` from `height: 100%` to `height: 100vh`

Comment: Fixed my problem! Thanks.